# Regex to match a google map coordinates from HTML script

Tags: javascript, regex, puppeteer

I was trying to scrape google map coordinates(lat,lng) from a website that embedded a google map
`document.querySelector("script")` gives me a javascript code in a string like this

```
    "
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(24.1759478919796,-32.45587603383785);

            function initialize()
            { 
            var mapProp = {  
                    center:myCenter,  
                    zoom:15, 
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);            
                var marker=new google.maps.Marker({  position:myCenter,  });            
                marker.setMap(map);
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            "
```

what i want a regex to match: `24.1759478919796,-32.45587603383785`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As those two numbers are the only ones that are terminated by a comma or closing parenthesis:

```js
let [lat, lng] = document.querySelector("script:not([src])").textContent
                         .match(/[.\d-]+(?=[,)])/g).map(Number);

console.log(lat, lng);
```

```html
<script>
var google = { maps: { LatLng: String } };
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(24.1759478919796,-32.45587603383785);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can get GPS coordinates from Google Maps place link. E.g. `https://www.google.com/maps/place/Starbucks/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x549069a98254bd17:0xb2f64f75b3edf4c3!8m2!3d47.5319688!4d-122.1942498!16s%2Fg%2F1tdfmzpb!19sChIJF71UgqlpkFQRw_Tts3VP9rI?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1`.

The Regex for this case may be like this: `/!3d(?<latitude>[^!]+)!4d(?<longitude>[^!]+)/gm`. It allows you to find and define groups using `matchAll` method. [Check how it works](https://regex101.com/r/mhqqWR/1):

```js
const placeUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Starbucks/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x549069a98254bd17:0xb2f64f75b3edf4c3!8m2!3d47.5319688!4d-122.1942498!16s%2Fg%2F1tdfmzpb!19sChIJF71UgqlpkFQRw_Tts3VP9rI?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1";
const urlPattern = /!3d(?<latitude>[^!]+)!4d(?<longitude>[^!]+)/gm;
const latitude = [...placeUrl.matchAll(urlPattern)].map(({ groups }) => groups.latitude)[0];
const longitude = [...placeUrl.matchAll(urlPattern)].map(({ groups }) => groups.longitude)[0];

console.log(JSON.stringify({latitude, longitude}));
```

Output:

```json
{
  "latitude":"47.5319688",
  "longitude":"-122.1942498"
}
```

If you want to know more about scraping Google Maps Places, you can check my blog post [Web Scraping Google Maps Places with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-google-maps-places-with-nodejs/).

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you:

```js
/-?(\d*\.)?\d+,\s*-?(\d*\.)?\d+/
```

here is full javascript code:

```js
let result = document.querySelector('script').textContent.match(/-?(\d*\.)?\d+,\s*-?(\d*\.)?\d+/g);

if (result.length >= 0) {
    let lng = Number.parseFloat(result[0].split(',')[0]);
    let lat = Number.parseFloat(result[0].split(',')[1]);
    console.log('%s, %s', lng, lat);
}
```

tested with:

`var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(24.1759478919796,-32.45587603383785);`

`var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(-24.1759478919796, -32);`

`var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(.1759478919796,   90)`